# "ValueError: Numeric class variable expected" error in Orange Data Mining

Tags: data-mining, orange

I'm doing an assignment and it requires us to learn and do orange data mining. I'm quite unfamiliar with the application and having a hard time finding anything regarding it. Due to this, I can't find the solution to my problem. As of now, I can't get rid of "ValueError: Numeric class variable expected"

I have attached what my Orange looks like and where I'm experiencing an error.
[image: Error]

I will also attach my dataset for reference.
[image: Dataset]

I do not know how to proceed, should I change my data's type? I tried with other datasets and I keep experiencing the same problem. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question. My Dr said I use the housing data, not the original dataset. But I don't understand it actually. Hope it can help you.

Comment: I got it. I used the wrong dataset. Maybe you can ignore the time and try it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the target variable is not recognized as such. Perhaps the role definition was lost somewhere between file import and regression. You can fix it using Select Columns.